# Sending Composite Types from JS to WCF REST Service

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

Here are the code snippets.

1.The complex object:

```
[DataContract]
public class NewUser
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Mobile")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "UserAddress")]
    public Address UserAddress { get; set; }
}
```

2.The Operation contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/RegisterUser", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
Guid Register(NewUser col);
```

3.The JS/Angular http post call

```
var newUser = {};

newUser.Email = $scope.col.Email;
newUser.FirstName = $scope.col.FirstName;
newUser.LastName = $scope.col.LastName;
newUser.Mobile = $scope.col.Mobile;
newUser.CityId = $scope.col.UserAddress.CityId;


$http.post(API_URL + "/RegisterUser", { col: newUser }).success(function (response) {
    if(response.status=="success" && !response.mailError){
        $scope.register = false;
        $scope.alert = {type:'success', msg:"You are successfully registered. Please check mail for the password. If you do not see the mail, check spams"};
    }else if(response.mailError){
    $scope.alert = {type:'warning', msg:'Unable to send mail! please try forgot password next time you need to login'};
    }else{
        $scope.alert = {type:'danger', msg:response.msg};
    }
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

4. The Result:
   The call is successful and the related Register function in the Service is called. However the NewUser object received has all properties set to NULL.

The values are correct from the JS side so its something thats not correct between the calls.
Any pointers ? My guess is that I am missing something obvious and very small but can't seem to figure out at the moment.

Comment: Please ignore the return values from WCF service back to JS as I am in the process of correcting those. However the core issue is receiving NULL at the Request part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. Here is the change needed.

Instead of using a col object to wrap the user object, we simply need to pass the user object to the service. So instead of

```
$http.post(API_URL + "/RegisterUser", { col: newUser }).success(function (response) {
```

we call

```
$http.post(API_URL + "/RegisterUser", newUser).success(function (response) {
```